# How can I get google earth building mesh data?

Tags: xml, api, 3d, google-earth, mesh

I'm making a an application and i would like to import the 3D buildings in google earth that you can find in Chi,NYC,SF, etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, due to licensing issues.

However, some 3D buildings in Google Earth come straight from [Google 3D Warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/), in which case they can be downloaded in COLLADA (.dae) or SketchUp (.skp) format.